# c++ gmock invoke other function with same args

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I want to create a mock to this function:

```
    bool func1(vector<string> data)
```

The real function should fill the vector and return true if it succeeded.
My mock should also fill the vector with values and return always true. how can I do it with gmock?

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. With that signature your function will, if anything, fill **a copy** of `data`, but not `data`itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified if this is member function, or a global one. Since you want to mock it in a C++ mocking framework, I will assume it is. Also, as Antonio said, if you want to modify the vector, you have to change the signature of your function and pass `data` using a reference. So, if `func1` is a member in class `MyClass`, you want to do the following.

Create an interface `IMyClass` and make your class implement that interface:

```
class IMyClass
{
public:
    virtual IMyClass() {}
    virtual bool func1(vector<string> &data) = 0;
}

class MyClass : public IMyClass
{
    bool func1(vector<string> &data) override
    {
        // Your code that modifies 'data'
    }
}
```

Then, make a mock class that also implements this interface using gmock:

```
class MyClassMock : public IMyClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(func1, bool(vector<string> &));
}
```

Finally, in your tests, you can mock calls to this function. Say you want to mock call that will set two strings ( `"str1"`, `"str2"` ) to vector `data`. This is what you would do in test body:

```
vector<string> dummyData = { string("str1"), string("str2") };
MyClassMock mockObj;
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, func1(_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(dummyData), Return(true)));
```

If `func1` is a global function, you can use the same approach by defining a small interface and calling it through that interface in your production code.